# Generate permutations of JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, permutation

I have an array of n different elements in javascript, I know there are n! possible ways to order these elements. I want to know what's the most effective (fastest) algorithm to generate all possible orderings of this array?

I have this code:

```
var swap = function(array, frstElm, scndElm) {

    var temp = array[frstElm];
    array[frstElm] = array[scndElm];
    array[scndElm] = temp;
}

var permutation = function(array, leftIndex, size) {

    var x;

    if(leftIndex === size) {

        temp = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            temp += array[i] + " ";
        }

        console.log("---------------> " + temp);

    } else {

        for(x = leftIndex; x < size; x++) {
            swap(array, leftIndex, x);
            permutation(array, leftIndex + 1, size);
            swap(array, leftIndex, x);
        }
    }
}

arrCities = ["Sidney", "Melbourne", "Queenstown"];
permutation(arrCities, 0, arrCities.length);
```

And it works, but I guess swapping every item to get the combinations is a bit expensive memory wise, I thought a good way of doing it is just focusing on the indexes of the array and getting all the permutations of the numbers, I'm wondering if there's a way of computing all of them without having to switch elements within the array? I guess recursively is possible to get all of them, I need help to do so.

So for example if I have:

```
arrCities = ["Sidney", "Melbourne", "Queenstown"];
```

I want the output to be:

```
[[012],[021],[102],[120],[201],[210]]
```

or:

```
[[0,1,2],
 [0,2,1],
 [1,0,2],
 [1,2,0],
 [2,0,1],
 [2,1,0]]
```

I'm reading this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations

But Wikipedia has never been good at explaining. I don't understand much of it, I have to say my math level isn't the best.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "most effective".  Fastest?  Lowest memory usage?

Comment: There are not n! permutations, unless you are absolutely sure all n elements in the array are different from each other (or, better, discernible). If two elements are indistinguishable you already have less that n! permutations (in fact, you'll have permutations with repetitions).

Comment: @EvanTrimboli is not the same, i want to do it by index not by element

Comment: Not really sure how it's different. Replace names with numbers and it's the same problem.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli that method has to switch the elements within to array to achieve all the permutations which i guess is too expensive speed (and memory) wise, im not good at math but my logic tells me there should be a method to calculate all possible number within a range and doing so would be way faster than having to actually relocate every element

Comment: Of course, you can figure out how many there are quite easily, that's just a formula. But you still need to generate the output. Which is still the same problem. Whether it's strings or numbers, they are still uniquely identifiable things that you want to generate permutations for.

Comment: Closing as duplicate of the originally suggested target. None of the answers here actually address the requirements in this question: your input is an Array, your output is an Array of all _indexes_ of permutations, but all answers answer the other question. The output `[ [ 012 ], [ 021 ],`…`]` is unlikely to be useful given that [such literals are deprecated](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal). Fortunately, all your use cases are covered by using the provided permutation functions with `array.map((_, index) => index)` as input instead of `array`.

Answer (score 47):

This function, `perm(xs)`, returns all the permutations of a given array:

```js
function perm(xs) {
  let ret = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i = i + 1) {
    let rest = perm(xs.slice(0, i).concat(xs.slice(i + 1)));

    if(!rest.length) {
      ret.push([xs[i]])
    } else {
      for(let j = 0; j < rest.length; j = j + 1) {
        ret.push([xs[i]].concat(rest[j]))
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

console.log(perm([1,2,3]).join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 10):

Using Heap's method (you can find it [in this paper](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/22m150.dir/2007/Permutation%20Generation%20Methods.pdf) which your Wikipedia article links to), you can generate all permutations of N elements with runtime complexity in O(N!) and space complexity in O(N). This algorithm is based on swapping elements. AFAIK this is as fast as it gets, there is no faster method to calculate all permutations.

For an implementation and examples, please have a look [at my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37580979/1647737) at the related question ["permutations in javascript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript).

Comment: What about some method tath doesn't calculate all possible permutations but makes a pretty close calculation?

Comment: @DSB I don't think I understand. If you don't want to generate all permutations but just a few, have a look at the [Lehmer code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code) which allows you to quickly compute individual permutations given a lexicographic permutation index.

Comment: Basic test using this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37580979/1647737) ran 10 times faster than @chacmoolvm answer above

Answer (score 9):

It is just for fun - my recursive solve in one string

```js
const perm = a => a.length ? a.reduce((r, v, i) => [ ...r, ...perm([ ...a.slice(0, i), ...a.slice(i + 1) ]).map(x => [ v, ...x ])], []) : [[]]
```

Comment: It takes ages to compute permutations of 11 elements.

Comment: Okay, I'm just conna say it now, I love one-liners. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Cool but unreadable too

Answer (score 2):

This is my version based on [le_m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647737/le-m)'s code:

```js
function permute(array) {
 Array.prototype.swap = function (index, otherIndex) {
  var valueAtIndex = this[index]

  this[index] = this[otherIndex]
  this[otherIndex] = valueAtIndex
 }

 var result = [array.slice()]

 , length = array.length

 for (var i = 1, heap = new Array(length).fill(0)
  ; i < length
 ;)
  if (heap[i] < i) {
   array.swap(i, i % 2 && heap[i])
   result.push(array.slice())
   heap[i]++
   i = 1
  } else {
   heap[i] = 0
   i++
  }

 return result
}

console.log(permute([1, 2, 3]))
```

This is my recursive JavaScript implementation of the same algorithm:

```js
Array.prototype.swap = function (index, otherIndex) {
 var valueAtIndex = this[index]

 this[index] = this[otherIndex]
 this[otherIndex] = valueAtIndex
}

Array.prototype.permutation = function permutation(array, n) {
 array = array || this
 n = n || array.length

 var result = []

 if (n == 1)
  result = [array.slice()]
 else {
  const nextN = n - 1

  for (var i = 0; i < nextN; i++) {
   result.push(...permutation(array, nextN))
   array.swap(Number(!(n % 2)) && i, nextN)
  }

  result.push(...permutation(array, nextN))
 }

 return result
}

console.log([1, 2, 3].permutation())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function permutations(str) {
 return (str.length <= 1) ? [str] :
         Array.from(new Set(
           str.split('')
              .map((char, i) => permutations(str.substr(0, i) + str.substr(i + 1)).map(p => char + p))
              .reduce((r, x) => r.concat(x), [])
         ));
}
```