# Filled Array with unique Elements - How can i copy it so i get every order possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, topological-sort

This is my first question here, I think the answer will be a small piece of Code.

Lets say i have a filled array at any lenght with unique elements:

```
let a = [A,B,C]
```

My question is,
How can I process the array, so that I have a list or x arrays , that show every possible order for these elements of the array above
like:

```
A,B,C
A,C,B
B,A,C
B,C,A
C,B,A
C,A,B
```

I dont really have an idea and tried to look in the web so far.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43260158

Comment: I found this guide online: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/

Answer (score 0):

The recursive idea is:

```
function order(list, ans){
    let size = list.length;
    if(size == 0){
        console.log(ans);
        return;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < size; i++){
        let first = list.shift();
        order(list, ans + `${first},`);
        list.push(first);
    }
}
```

Basically, for each element, you set it as a first and recursively do the same thing with the rest of the list.